# performance of icc main.cpp == g++ -ffast-math main.cpp

Tags: floating-point, computer-arithmetic

I have a program that has a nested loop, together with its parent running at $O(n^2)$ complexity performing floating point arithmetic.

I see that the performance of the code when compiled with `icc` is comparable to that of `g++ -ffast-math`.

Does this mean that icc is switching on an equivalent of the `-ffast-math` implicitly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To first order approximation, icc does use `-ffast-math` by default.

If you run `icc --help`, it will show you its options. One of the sections is `Floating Point`, which begins like this:

```
Floating Point
--------------

-fp-model <name>
          enable <name> floating point model variation
            [no-]except - enable/disable floating point semantics
            fast[=1|2]  - enables more aggressive floating point optimizations
            precise     - allows value-safe optimizations
            source      - enables intermediates in source precision
            strict      - enables -fp-model precise -fp-model except, disables
                          contractions and enables pragma stdc fenv_access
            double      - rounds intermediates in 53-bit (double) precision
            extended    - rounds intermediates in 64-bit (extended) precision
```

It doesn't say it here, but in [icc documentation here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522979), it says that `fast=1` is the default.

The other options similar to `-ffast-math` are:

```
-[no-]prec-sqrt
          determine if certain square root optimizations are enabled
-[no-]prec-div
          improve precision of FP divides (some speed impact)
-[no-]fast-transcendentals
          generate a faster version of the transcendental functions
...
-[no-]ftz
          enable/disable flush denormal results to zero
-[no-]fma
          enable/disable the combining of floating point multiplies and
          add/subtract operations
```

E.g., [fused multiply-adds are on by default](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522978), and [precise square root is off by default](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522990).

But the correspondence between `-ffast-math` and `-fp-model fast=1` is probably not very precise - it could well be that some other specific options are included in `fast-math` ([which can be seen here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath)) but excluded in `fp-model fast=1` or vice versa. It looks to me like among other things `-ffast-math` would disable non-finite floating-point arithmetic (`inf`, `nan`), which icc doesn't do by default.

Comment: So does `icc` prioritise speed over accuracy ?

Comment: @kesari Yes, but it is a choice of defaults - it is easy to pick `-fp-model` that suits you best. Given how common the flag `-ffast-math` is for gcc projects, I don't think it represents any kind of real difference between the two compilers.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out by asking icc and g++ to print out all the optimization switches that are actually enabled. Look at the verbosity options for each.

Comment: How do  I do that ?

Comment: The '-v' option to both seems to give what you need for both compilers. You may have to work backwards from some switches to know if they are implied by a higher-level one.